# can't find notify syslog in cisco sw nexus 3000

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, syslog

in cisco IOS i was used "Configuration Change Notification and Logging"

but in cisco sw-nexuis i can't fine the commend

```
SW-nex3000(config)# archive
SW-nex3000(config-archive)# log config
                          ^
% Invalid command at '^' marker.
SW-nex3000(config-archive)# notify syslog
                          ^
% Invalid command at '^' marker.
SW-nex3000(config-archive)#
```

i need to send any Configuration Change Notification to syslog server

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, NX-OS doesn't have a command equivalent to IOS' `archive`.  Sending accounting logs to syslog is not supported, though you can send them to a TACACS or RADIUS server.